running website on another url when previous isnt available
We have a website (angular,node.js) and 3 domains. When the first domain is not be available, the same website must work on the second domain. And if the second isn't available then it must work on third domain. We are working with windows IIS server and we need to do it with configuration.txt file. Our main website has one domain for frontend and the other for api, but api will be different for second and third domains.
iisreverse-proxyconfigurationnode.jswindows-server-2022
